# ArangoDB: Custom labels for edges and vertices in Graph Viewer

Tags: arangodb

I have a collection 'presidents':

```
{"_key": "1", "name": "George Washington"},
{"_key": "2","name": "John Adams"},
{"_key": "3", "name": "Thomas Jefferson"},
{"_key": "4", "name": "James Madison"}
```

and an edge collection 'presidents_relations':

```
{"_from": "presidents/1", "_to": "presidents/4", "linkType": "likes"},
{"_from": "presidents/3", "_to": "presidents/1", "linkType": "likes"},
{"_from": "presidents/2", "_to": "presidents/4", "linkType": "hates"},
{"_from": "presidents/1", "_to": "presidents/2", "linkType": "likes"},
{"_from": "presidents/1", "_to": "presidents/3", "linkType": "hates"}
```

If I import these into the Graph Viewer, I get this result:
[image: Graph without labels]

This is not very informative. What I would like instead is something like this:
[image: Graph with labels]

Is there a way to do this in the Graph Viewer? Preferably with an AQL command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the graph viewer:

**1.) Create a graph**

Edge definition "*presidents_relations*" and from & to collections as "*presidents*"

[image]

**2.) Modify display settings**

Open the graph display settings menu (top-right menu icon) and set
the node label to "*name*" and the edge label to "*linkType*". Apply those settings by pressing the "Save" button.

[image]

AQL only solution is currently not possible but may be included in the future.

Comment: I just noticed: Your approach works if I create a new graph in the 'Graphs' section of the web interface.
But not if I execute the AQL command 
    'FOR doc IN presidents_relations RETURN doc'
and click on 'Graph Viewer' in the query result. This is a little inconvenient since in my actual database, I only want to view a subset of all nodes and edges. Is there a workaround; or a way to create a graph of a subset without creating a new collection?